# Initialising arrays of objects

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, initialization

I'm new to Java so this might be a dumb question. Say I create a class called SomeObject with simple getters and setters for some parameter. Next I want to create an array of 3 instances of that object. Can anyone tell me what's the difference between:

```
SomeObject[] objectArray = {new SomeObject(),new SomeObject(),new SomeObject()};
objectArray[0].setValue(10);
```

and:

```
SomeObject[] objectArray = new SomeObject[3];
objectArray[0].setValue(10);
```

In the first case I can perfectly well get the value of objects[0]:

```
System.out.println(objectArray[0].getValue());
```

..while the latter gives a NullPointerException while trying to set the value. Am I missing something or could it be I made some mistake of a different kind?

Comment: *I create a class called `Object`* even in an example, I won't recommend doing this. Rename it at least to `MyObject`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is right, doing that is very confusing for people trying to read your code to help you out

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create an array of objects, you actually need 2 steps

1. Create the array
2. Create the objects

The first method does both, while the 2nd method does only step one, thus the references to the actual objects are `null`.

```
Object[] objects = {new Object(),new Object(),new Object()};
```

Here the `{...}` creates the array and the inner `new`s create the objects.

```
Object[] objects = new Object[3];
```

Here the `new` creates the array of size 3. But individual elements, such as `object[0]` are not created and thus the reference is `null`, and this causes the exception.

Comment: I think that cleared it up for me. My confusion here was that simply creating the array did not create the members, if I'm correct?

Comment: @Leto you are absolutely correct, you need to create the array and then create the contents

Comment: Beginner's mistake I guess :) .. Thank you all for your support!

Comment: @Leto yeah it happens, especially if you are more experienced in a language that does it differently ( like i was with C++ once ). Btw if you feel this has answered the question satisfactorily, you can accept it as an answer by clicking the green tick to the left

Answer (score 2):

Your first line of code creates three `Object`s to fill the array with.

Your second line of code creates an empty array and never fills it, so it's still full of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The second version, `Object[] objects = new Object[3];`, creates an array of size three, but the objects don't exist, they're null.

The first one, `Object[] objects = {new Object(),new Object(),new Object()};` explicitly creates the objects at the same time the array is created, so you can access them

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the second way, you can try this:

```
SomeObject[] objectArray = new SomeObject[3]; 
objectArray[0] = new SomeObject(); //create SomeObject
objectArray[0].setValue(10); //give SomeObject the value of 10
```